# julian century, Matlab

Tags: matlab, julian-date

I have to calculate the time in julian century (Matlab).

I used the fuction "juliandate" to calculate the time for every hour.

Julian century is just the julian date divided for 36525?

```
t1 = datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0);
t2 = datetime(2000,12,31,23,59,0);
date = t1:hours(1):t2;
date=transpose(date);
jd=juliandate(date);
jc=jd/36525;
```

Comment: According to https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/juliandate.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#buh3k1j-2 "A Julian date is the number of days and fractional days since noon on November 24, 4714 BCE in the proleptic Gregorian calendar, or January 1, 4713 BCE in the proleptic Julian calendar." To the best of my knowledge a Julian century is an interval of 36525 days, but the writer must specify the date that is considered 0. I very much doubt that date is November 24, 4714 BCE in your application.

Comment: Yes you're right, I found it. 0 is the 1st of January 1900. Therefore I just have to count the days since that date, also considering hours and minutes and than divide it for 36525